# Strategy or Visitor?

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

**Setting:**

I have a series of classes, each acting as a proxy to a different webservice. These classes all implement one of the two leaf interfaces of the following structure:

```
interface IWebService
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> Get();
}

interface IWebServiceReference : IWebService
{
    decimal Get(string toCode);
}

interface IWebServiceTable : IWebService
{
    decimal Get(string fromCode, string toCode);
}
```

I'm attempting to create a class `WebServiceContext` that encapsulates the concrete classes and make them interchangeable. However, because these concrete classes implementing a interface hierarchy, I don't need to try it to know I won't get the expected results.

**Question:**

I never used the *visitor* pattern before, but is this type of situation that calls for that pattern?

If so, should I use it, or can I avoid the code maintenance complexity it introduces by somehow improving my current design in a way that allows me to implement the *Strategy* pattern?

Comment: sounds more like a Facade pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern is a way of separating an algorithm from an object structure it operates on.

What you are describing sounds more like a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern:

> A facade is an object that provides a
>   simplified interface to a larger body
>   of code, such as a class library

Comment: I don't need to operate on all concrete classes at once. When I use the encapsulating class, I pass it a reference to the concrete class I want to use. Each concrete class works on isolation and never uses the other concrete classes.